# Coldfusion - Query a database not case-sensitive

Tags: sql, coldfusion

The result of this query is to be able to input and get a query returned (all while ignoring case).

---

For example:

If I have these columns in my table-> id, first name, last name

**For id**

I can type in 151, 442, 112 and it should return my results

**For first name**

I can type in JiM, jim or JIM and it should return my results

**For last name**

I can type in Smith, smith, SMITH or SmiTH and it should return my results

The aim is to provide case-insensitivity to both the user (who is inputting the data, and the database - because each record is **unique** to the database so I shouldn't need to worry if I type in a first/last name combination such as jim smith or JIM SMITH)

This is within my WHERE clause

```
WHERE #firstname# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#firstnamevar#%" />
```

---

---

My question is do I need to use lower(), LCASE(), a mixture of these two or something completely different to find a solution to this question?

Comment: wrap both sides of the equality with UPPER or LOWER

Comment: @Randy outside of the variable tags?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You would need a _ColdFusion_ function ([`LCASE/UCASE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7b1c.html)) to convert the `#firstnamevar#` variable. Then a _database string function_ to convert the table column values within the SQL. The latter is database specific. Can you update the question tags to indicate database and version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UPPER right before the database column and UCase right before the param value.  Also, you dont need pound signs around firstname. Like this:

```
WHERE UPPER(firstname)
LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#UCase(firstnamevar)#%" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a sql server database you don't have to do anything because it does case insensitive searches on varchar columns.

Otherwise, you apply the upper() function to the sql field and ucase() to the ColdFusion variable.  Something like this:

```
where upper(firstname) 
like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#ucase(firstnamevar)#%>
```

However, this will be slow.  It might be worthwhile to store an uppercase version of the field in your db, with an index.  Then you can do this:

```
where upperCaseFirstName
like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#ucase(firstnamevar)#%>
```

By the way, you posted this,

```
 WHERE #firstname# 
 LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#firstnamevar#%" >
```

Unless you have a variable named firstname, the octothorps will cause an error.

Comment: Routine (upper) ambiguous - more than one routine resolves to given signature. < Error. with the line: UPPER(#firstname#) LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#UCase(firstnamevar)#%" />

Comment: What's the error message?  Undefined variable would be my guess.